# remove "-" from my clock javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove this dash "-" that is showing up next to my days, hours, minutes etc. I can not seem to figure it out how on my javascript. I am just updating it making it look newer  any ideas on how would remove the dash example "-45days"

http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/pen/cqnmD

```
// set the date we're counting down to
var target_date = new Date('Jan, 31, 2014').getTime();

// variables for time units
var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

// get tag element
var countdown = document.getElementById('clock');

// update the tag with id "countdown" every 1 second
setInterval(function () {

// find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
var current_date = new Date().getTime();
var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

// do some time calculations
days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

// format countdown string + set tag value
clock.innerHTML = '<span class="days">' + days +  ' <b>Days</b></span> <span class="hours">' + hours + ' <b>Hours</b></span> <span class="minutes">'
+ minutes + ' <b>Minutes</b></span> <span class="seconds">' + seconds + ' <b>Seconds</b></span>';  

}, 1000);
```

Comment: You're seeing a negative number.

Comment: Your date is in the past, ofcourse all the values are negative...

Comment: You're "counting down" to a day in the past.  It's not a "dash" insomuch as it's a *minus sign*.  You're getting a *negative* number.

Comment: Ok I will have to leave it in there the minus sign just reset date also. Cheers all.

Comment: Why are you doing `parseInt(seconds_left / 3600)`?  The `/` operator will not return you a string!  If you want to truncate a number, use `Math.floor(seconds_left / 3600)`.  Using `parseInt` will cause it to convert your number to a string and then back to a number!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually a minus, not a dash, just swap the target_date and current_date in the calculation:

```
var seconds_left = (current_date - target_date) / 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Select a date in the future if you want to see a positive time before this date arrives.

If you really want to have a positive number, you can use the `Math.abs()` method

```
'<span class="days">' + Math.abs(days) +  ' <b>Days</b></span> <span class="hours">' + Math.abs(hours) + ' <b>Hours</b></span> <span class="minutes">'
+ Math.abs(minutes) + ' <b>Minutes</b></span> <span class="seconds">' + Math.abs(seconds) + ' <b>Seconds</b></span>';
```

But then you should add something to indicate that this time is in the past (a "ago" could be nice)